# Month wise data fetch from date field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table name `billing` and my table data looks like below

| id | site_name | billing_date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 2021-01-15 | 100 |
| 2 | abc | 2021-02-15 | 80 |
| 3 | abc | 2021-03-15 | 120 |
| 4 | abc | 2021-04-15 | 110 |
| 5 | abc | 2021-05-15 | 105 |
| 6 | abc | 2021-06-15 | 90 |
| 7 | abc | 2021-07-15 | 106 |
| 8 | abc | 2021-08-15 | 70 |
| 9 | xyz | 2021-01-15 | 100 |
| 10 | xyz | 2021-02-15 | 90 |
| 11 | xyz | 2021-03-15 | 200 |
| 12 | xyz | 2021-04-15 | 300 |

My expected result will be like this data

| site_name | Year | January | February | March | Arpil | May | June | July | August | September | October | November | December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2021 | 100 | 80 | 120 | 110 | 105 | 90 | 106 | 70 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| xyz | 2021 | 100 | 90 | 200 | 300 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Moreover `site_name`,`abc` month `January` has only one record, `February` has only one record same as other months. I have tried the below code but I don't get my expected output

```
select site_name, YEAR(billing_date) as YearName, monthname(billing_date) as monthName, amount
    from bills
    group by site_name, YEAR(billing_date),monthname(billing_date),amount
    order by site_name;
```

Please any suggestions on how to get my expected output

Comment: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: @jarlh, Thank you so much. I will try this way what you suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the following link of @jarlh I have solved my problem as below code. It is really helpful for me and what I want.

```
SELECT site_name, YearName 
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  1 THEN amount END) January      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  2 THEN amount END) February      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  3 THEN amount END) March      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  4 THEN amount END) April      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  5 THEN amount END) May      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  6 THEN amount END) June      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  7 THEN amount END) July      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  8 THEN amount END) August      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  9 THEN amount END) September      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  10 THEN amount END) October   
, SUM(CASE WHEN month =  11 THEN amount END) November      
, SUM(CASE WHEN month = 12 THEN amount END) December   
FROM (SELECT ems_table.electric_bills.* 
    , EXTRACT(YEAR  FROM last_billing_date) YearName              
    , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM last_billing_date) month           
    FROM ems_table.electric_bills) 
    alias_table  GROUP BY site_name, YearName ORDER BY site_name ASC;
```